# Android Sharedpreferance saving array list issue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Saving the data is done but I am not able to retrieve the data it showing

> java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Here my code.(Save)

> ```
>                    List<String> historyList = new ArrayList<>();
>                    historyList.add(data.get(position).getProductName());
>                    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
>                    set.addAll(historyList);
>                    preference.save("History", set);
> ```

(Retrieve)

> ```
>   Log.d("History", "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"  +preference.readString("History",""));
> ```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saving the `Set` you need to retrieve the `Set` instead to `String`and you can convert it to `List` again.

```
 Set<String> set = preference.getStringSet("History", null);
 List<String> historyList = new ArrayList<>();
 historyList.addAll(set);
```

Comment: May I know Why this is down voted

Comment: Code only answers are not good. It's better to add an explanation accompanying your code

Comment: @Micho Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

After you prepare ArrayList of all items, convert it to a comma separated String.

```
String itemsString = TextUtils.join(",", historyList);
preference.save("History", itemsString);
```

When you retrieve it, convert it back into an Array.

```
String [] itemsArray = preference.readString("History","").split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the values

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonText = Prefs.getString("key", null);
String[] text = gson.fromJson(jsonText, String[].class);  //EDIT: gso to gson
```

Set the values

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<String> historyList = new ArrayList<>();
historyList.addAll(data);
String jsonText = gson.toJson(historyList);
prefsEditor.putString("key", jsonText);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your array list to preference by converting them to string.

First convert your array to string using `Gson`.

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> yourlist=new ArrayList<>();
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
```

> Fill your array

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
String myfav = gson.toJson(yourlist);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("myfav", myfav);
 editor.commit();
```

Then read this string where you need this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("myfav", null);
```

Now get back your array list in following way:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CustomObject>>() { }.getType();
       ArrayList<CustomObject> yourfinallist=new ArrayList<>();
       gson = new Gson();
       yourfinallist = gson.fromJson(myfav, type);
```